# Terraform: Get the module name to inject it to other module from the path

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+, terraform-modules

I need to get the terraform parent module name from the path and then pass it as a variable to other module.  Is it possible?.
Example:
From the module child1, it can access to the directory src/yaml in the module child2

### Parent module:

```
module "parent" {
  source = "s3::https://s3.amazonaws.com/tf-modules-zip/child1.zip"
  some_variable = "foo"
}
```

### Child1 module:

```
variable "some_variable" {
  type        = string
  description = "Any value"
}

locals {
  os_module_name = this.module.name
  path_to_yamls  = "${local.os_module_name}.child2/src/yaml"
}

module "child1" {
  source = "s3::https://s3.amazonaws.com/tf-modules-zip/child2.zip"
  some_variable = var.some_variable
  path_to_yaml_files = local.path_to_yamls
}
```

### Child2 module:

```
variable "some_variable" {
  type        = string
  description = "Any value"
}

variable "path_to_yaml_files" {
  type        = string
  description = "Path to retrieve the yaml files"
}

locals {
  path_to_configs = var.path_to_yaml_files
  exclusions    = yamldecode(file("${local.path_to_configs}/exclusions.yaml"))
}

resource "null_resource" "child2" {
  local-exec { 
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash" ,"-c"],
    command = <<-EOT
      exec "command1 -yaml ${local.exclusions}"
      exec "command2 -var ${var.some_variable}"
    EOT
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It's possible!.  Just using the module path to extract the parent portion and then concatenate it to the child1 path.

## ANSWER

### Parent module:

**main.tf**

```
module "parent" {
  source = "s3::https://s3.amazonaws.com/tf-modules-zip/child1.zip" # <-- Calling the child1 module
  some_variable = "foo"                                             # <-- Assigning the foo value to some_variable
}
```

### Child1 module:

**child1.tf**

```
variable "some_variable" {                                          # <-- Input variable
  type        = string
  description = "Any value"
}

locals {
  parent_module_name    = path.module != "." ? regex(".*/([^/]+)?", path.module)[0] : "."   ### <-- Extracting the parent module name from the current module path
  path_to_yamls         = "${path.module}/../${local.parent_module_name}.child1/src/yaml"   ### <-- Concatenating the parent module name with the child2 module path
}

module "child1" {
  source = "s3::https://s3.amazonaws.com/tf-modules-zip/child2.zip" # <-- Calling the child2 module
  some_variable = var.some_variable                                 # <-- Injecting the value of var.some_variable to the child2 module
  path_to_yaml_files = local.path_to_yamls                          # <-- Injecting the value of local.path_to_yamls to the child2 module
}
```

### Child2 module:

**child2.tf**

```
variable "some_variable" {                                          # <-- Input variable
  type        = string
  description = "Any value"
}

variable "path_to_yaml_files" {                                     # <-- Input variable
  type        = string
  description = "Path to retrieve the yaml files"
}

locals {
  path_to_configs = var.path_to_yaml_files                                      # <-- Using the injected value in var.path_to_yaml_files from the child1 module
  exclusions    = yamldecode(file("${local.path_to_configs}/exclusions.yaml"))  # <-- Using the injected value in var.path_to_yaml_files from the child1 module
}

resource "null_resource" "child2" {
  local-exec { 
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash" ,"-c"],
    command = <<-EOT
      exec "command1 -yaml ${local.exclusions}"                     # <-- Using the injected value in var.path_to_yaml_files from the child1 module
      exec "command2 -var ${var.some_variable}"                     # <-- Using the injected value in var.path_to_yaml_files from the child1 module
    EOT
  }
}
```

## Explanation:

When we do a "terraform init", the modules are downloaded in the parent path under this structure:

```
-[example]
   main.tf
 |--[.terraform]
    |--[modules]
       |--[parent]
            child1.tf
       |--[parent.child1]
            child2.tf
          |--[src]
             |--[yaml]
                  file1.yaml
                  file2.yaml
                  file3.yaml
```

Usig the "path.module" do the trick.  It gets the module path from it's called.  In this example, it's being called from child1 which has the name "parent".  Then,
the expression: "${path.module}/../${local.parent_module_name}.child1/src/yaml" tells to terraform that it has to go up a level and then go to the "parent.child1/src/yaml"
directory after the interpolation of the "${local.parent_module_name}" variable which has the value "parent".

The advantage of this method is that the parent module name can be changed in the main.tf file and afer to do a "terraform init -upgrade", the directory structure takes the new
value.

I hope this helps a lot!.